# Trying to Add New Scaffolded Item

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget-package

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and creating new Asp.net Core MVC application using dotnet Core 6.0 framework and following nuget packages:

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 6.0
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0
   but adding new scaffolded item following error message is showing:

There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MvcMovie'.'

[image]

I have tried to change the versions of dotnet core and nuget packages but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Package
> restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MvcMovie'.'

I add packages 6.0.0 and reproduce your problem, then I try to replace the packages like below(dotnet Core 6.0 framework), then it works, you can have a try:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 6.0.21
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6.0.21
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 6.0.16
```